# How to use Nuxt + Cypress + CircleCI?

Tags: testing, configuration, nuxt.js, cypress, circleci

## What I want to do?

I want to run Cypress tests on CircleCI for my Nuxt project

## What's my problem?

In local mode it works fine, but I can't get it to work in CircleCI

I've already tried the CircleCI orb `cypress-io / cypress @ 1.28.0`, but just using `wait-on` the tests start before the `npm run dev` finishes.

```
 - cypress / running:
      requires:
        - ramp up
      start: npm start
      wait: 'http: // localhost: 8181'
      cache-key:> -
        v1-dependencies - {{checksum "package.json"}}
      filters:
        Marking:
          only: /.*/
        branches:
          only: /.*/
```

CircleCI is also not starting the app, I don't know why :(

[image]
[image]

## What do I think is going on?

I tried this command bash `curl -o /dev /null -u localhost:8181 /login -Isw '%{http_code}\n'localhost:8181 /login` and even if Nuxt is compiling they return code 200 so I I think Nuxt becomes the available route even if it's not compiled.

## Help

Does anyone know any Nuxt projects configured with Cypress and CircleCI for me to see?

This print means that the visit was sucessufy executed and failed on assertion?

[image]

```js
import { Response } from 'miragejs'

context('Login', () => {
  it('should login after button click', () => {
    cy.login({
      username: 'titular@ampa.ro',
      password: 'password',
    })

    cy.url()
      .should('eq', 'http://localhost:8181/')
  })

  it('should return invalid credentials', () => {
    cy.mirage((server) => {
      server.post('session', () => new Response(400, {}, {
        errorCode: 'credential_invalid',
        type: 'badRequestError',
        errorMessage: 'Credential invalid',
        errors: {},
      }))
    })

    cy.login({
      username: 'titular@ampa.ro',
      password: 'password',
    })

    cy.get('body').should('include.text', 'Credenciais inválidas')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can solve my problem

That was my CircleCI job to run e2e tests on `config.yml`:

```
test-e2e:
docker:
  - image: cypress/base:10
parallelism: 2
steps:
  - checkout
  - restore_cache:
      keys:
        - cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
  - run:
      name: Install dependencies
      command: npm ci
  - run: npm run cypress:verify
  - save_cache:
      key: cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      paths:
        - ~/.npm
        - ~/.cache
  - run:
      name: Run Nuxt App
      command: npm run dev
      background: true
  - run:
      name: Run E2E
      command: npm run cypress:run
```

That was my package scripts related to e2e tests on `package.json`:

```
"dev": "nuxt",
"cypress:open": "cypress open",
"cypress:run": "cypress run",
"cypress:verify": "cypress verify",
"test:e2e": "start-server-and-test dev 8181 cypress:open"
```

And finally, thats are my `cypress.json` changes to make this works:

```
"defaultCommandTimeout":  60000,
```

Now, my e2e tests are running very well!

Answer (score -1):

I am on the Developer Experience team at Cypress.

We have recently published a guide for [CircleCI](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/circleci) which details the solution deployed in the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/) repo.

Comment: I already read this article, but unfortunately doesn't help me :(